# I made one theorem (with proof) does it already exist?

Tags: computer-science, computability

**Notations**:

- $\mathbb{F}(\left\{0;1\right \})$ is the set of all finit word on $\left\{0;1\right \}$
- let $m \in\left\{0;1\right \}^{\mathbb{N}} $ then $m|_n$ is the finit word of size n which coincide with the first n character of m
- let $m \in \mathbb{F}(\left\{0;1\right \})$ and $m' \in \mathbb{F}(\left\{0;1\right \})$ or $\in \left\{0;1\right \}^{\mathbb{N}}$ then $m+m'$ is the concatenation of m and m'
- let $m \in \mathbb{F}(\left\{0;1\right \})$ and $m' \in \mathbb{F}(\left\{0;1\right \})$ or $\in \left\{0;1\right \}^{\mathbb{N}}$ then $m<m'$ mean the begin of $m'$ is $m$ and $m \neq m'$
- let $m_1 < m_2 < m_3 ....$, then $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow +\infty} m_n$ is the word which have for nth character the nth character of $m_n$

**Theorem :** let  $f: \left\{0;1\right \}^{\mathbb{N}} \times \mathbb{N}  \rightarrow \left\{0;1\right \}   $: such that

- $\forall m \in \left\{0;1\right \}^{\mathbb{N}}, \exists n \in\mathbb{N}$ such that
  $\forall p> n: f(m,p) = f(m,n)$
- $\forall m \in \left\{0;1\right \}^{\mathbb{N}}$ $\forall m' \in \left\{0;1\right \}^{\mathbb{N}}$,
  $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$: $m|_n= m'|_n \implies f(m,n)=f(m',n)$
- let g be:

  \begin{array}{}
    \left\{0;1\right \}^{\mathbb{N}}\rightarrow \left\{0;1\right \}\\
          \ m \rightarrow \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty} f(m,n)
   \end{array}

well defined by hypothesis one.
Third and last hypothesis is: $\forall m \in\left\{0;1\right \}^{\mathbb{N}} $and $  \forall l \in \mathbb{F}(\left\{0;1\right \}): g(l+m)= g(m)$

Then the result: $g$ is constant.

**Remarks:**

- let's $m$ be a finit word and $k\leq m$ size and $M$ infinite word such that $m<M$  then we introduce the notation $f(m,k)$ equal by definition to $f(M,k)$. Notation well define by the second hypothesis.
- let m and m' be two infinite word then $m|_0 = m'|_0 = \emptyset$. And so by hypotheisis 2: $f(m,0)= f(m',0)$
- the spirit of the first two propriety is to abstract the concept of a function from $ \left\{0;1\right \}^{\mathbb{N}}$ to $\left\{0;1\right \}   $ that can see  a finish amont of the entry word in a finite time, have an infinite time to give its answer, but after a finite time its answer need to stay the same.
- strangly we don't need f computable as a supplementary hypothesis, so you can say i'm on wrong forum lol.

**proof**: by absurd, let's suppose g is not constant. Then let's prove this by recursion:
$\exists m_1,m_2,m_3....   $all in $\mathbb{F}(\left\{0;1\right \})$ such that:

- $m_1 < m_2 < m_3...$
- for all n $\in N$ we note $x_n$ the size of $m_n$ then  $f(m_n,x_n -1)\ne f(m_n,x_n)$

construction of $m_1$: there is m and m' $\in \left\{0;1\right \}^{\mathbb{N}}$ such that
$g(m) \neq g(m')$ meaning $\exists n $ such that $\forall k\geq n: f(m,k)\neq f(m',k)$ we take n minimum
whose verify the last proposition. n is at least one cause $f(m,0) = f(m',0)$. Then as $f(m,n-1) = f(m', n-1)$ but  $f(m,n) \neq f(m', n)$ we deduce $[f(m,n) \neq f(m,n-1)$ or $f(m',n) \neq f(m',n-1)]$. Let's say $f(m,n) \neq f(m,n-1)$. Now we take $m_1= m|_n$ and $x_1 = n$ ($= m_1$ size).

construction of $m_n$: let h be:

\begin{array}{}
  \left\{0;1\right \}^{\mathbb{N}}\rightarrow \left\{0;1\right \}\\
        \ m \rightarrow \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty} f(m_{n-1}+m,n)
 \end{array}

as we can see: $\forall m \in \left\{0;1\right \}^{\mathbb{N}}: h(m) = g(m_{n-1}+m) = g(m)$ by the last hypothese, so $h=g$ and as $g$ non constante so is $h$.
There is m and m' $\in \left\{0;1\right \}^{\mathbb{N}}$ such that
$h(m) \neq h(m')$ meaning $\exists p $ such that $\forall k\geq p: f(m_{n-1}+m,k)\neq f(m_{n-1}+m',k)$ we take p minimum whose verify the last proposition. p is at least $m_{n-1}$ size $+ 1$ cause $\forall k<m_{n-1}$ size  + 1$: f(m_{n-1}+m,k)=f(m_{n-1}+m',k)=f(m_{n-1},k)$.
Then as $f(m_{n-1}+m,p-1) = f(m_{n-1}+m', p-1)$ but  $f(m_{n-1}+m,p) \neq f(m_{n-1}+m', p)$ we deduce $[f(m_{n-1}+m,p) \neq f(m_{n-1}+m,p-1)$ or $f(m_1+m',p) \neq f(m_{n-1}+m',p-1)]$. Let's say $f(m_{n-1}+m,p) \neq f(m_{n-1}+m,p-1)$. Now we take $m_n= (m_{n-1}+m)|_p$ and $x_n = p$ ($=m_n$ size)

Conclusion: by recursion we made our construction. Let M= $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow +\infty} m_n$ then:
$\forall n\in \mathbb{N}: f(m,x_n-1) = f(m_n,x_n-1) \neq f(m_n,x_n) = f(m,x_n)$ and so M violate the first hypothesis. Contradiction, by the absurd g is constant.

thank you for reading

edited: number -> word

Comment: Ummm... what is your question?  Whether this result is known?

Comment: does this theorem have already be discovered ? (and did i made mistake in the proof)

Comment: Maybe this should be posted in cs.stackexchange

Comment: thank you for advice, i will do that tomorrow if nobody in this laps on time can say this result already exist, is direct consequence of already known result or is wrong

Comment: Congratulations for your theorem! I don't know if this is known but your result is correct. I also think the proof is but didn't check in every detail.
We can generalize it a bit in the language of $$-automata: if $L$ is an [$$-language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_language) stable by translation, whose complementary is also stable by translation, then $L$ and its complementary cannot both be recognized by a deterministic [Büchi automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BCchi_automaton).

Comment: On the last wikipedia page I linked, under the section "Deterministic versus non-deterministic Büchi automata", the argument showing that $(0∪1)*0^$ is not recognizable by a Büchi automaton is in essence your proof (if I understood it correctly).

Comment: interesting but i answer tommorow cause i need to sleep.

Comment: so: 1) yes i never thought of that cause i have no informatic knowledge but yes the theorem can be seen as accepted langage. More specicly we suppress last hypothesis. We say a word is accepted if g(m) = 1. Then theorem said it cannot accept a non trivial language L such that F({0,1}) include in L (which you called stable by translation if i understood well)

Comment: in my last post change  F({0,1}) by  F({0,1})+L  2) ty for genralisation cause i will need something of this kind for the rest of my work 3) the axiom on f makes it stronger than an automaton but still tx for reference. 4) the Proof of (0∪1)∗0^ω is not recognizable is not the same cause it use ciclycity of automaton which i can't use 5) i ve no informatic experience (i didnt knew what was a regular language) so im not sure but by what i ve understood of the language accepted by Büchi automaton it seems if f is Büchi automata.my theorem is trivial consequence. But again f here can be stronger.

Comment: 6) and the most important. In the "language accepted" version of my theorem: accepted mean at a moment exit ALWAIS 1. In Büchi automaton its just AN IFINITE time the same specific exit. At first glance i thought, well, acceptation is ruder on my theorem. But no thats actually the same, cause let's start with a Büchi automaton acceptation process on an accepted word, i can alwais make a new fonction plug the hole where the specific exit is not there between 2 place where she is, which give at the end an exit which stabilise (not sure im clear here).

Comment: point of last comment is i can suppress first hypothesis, change g by g(m) = 1 <=> their exist infinite n such that g(m,n) = 1. And theorem hold true with one less hypothesis. I will maybe edit my original post to show this theorem variation

Comment: To answer to someone, you can use @username so that this person is notified of your answer.

Comment: I said "stable by translation" but it's a bad wording.

Yes, a Büchi automaton needs to be finite but my point was that your argument is the one used to show that $(0∪1)^*0^$ is not recognizable by a deterministic Büchi automaton (and it also works for "infinite" deterministic Büchi automata). You can make variations on this same idea. For instance, you can suppose that if $m|_n = m'|_n$, then $g(m) = g(m')$ instead of your hypothesis.

About your alternative definition of $g$, this doesn't define a single function except in the case where $\lim_n g(m,n)$ exists.

Comment: @Idéophage 1) I made a mistake sry:  g(m) = 1 <=> their exist infinite n such that f(m,n) = 1. But i wil write the prove of equivalence in original post after a nap and all will be more clear. 2) Maybe there is similarity between the 2 proofs but it speak of state when here f is not even computable, ...mwell its little bit subjective. See you for the (short) proof of new theorem version.

Comment: But what about $f(m,n) = m_{n-1}$ if $n>0$ and $f(m,0) = 0$? Then $g$ is not constant, right? [Ah I see that I wrote that you can suppose instead that $m|_n = m'|_n$ implies $g(m) = g(m')$ but it is not at all what I meant to say. I meant to say that if there is some $n$ such that $m_k = m'_k$ for all $k>n$, then $g(m) = g(m')$.]

Comment: aie, new version of theorem have failed. The goal was to change g so we can supress hypothesis one. So we had a f which verified only hypothesis 2 but not 1 the natural path of proof was to rebuilt a f' which satisfy the 2 hypothesis by "pluging the holes" in f but i end up with a fonction verifying hyp 1 but no longer hyp 2 grrr. I spend 2 hours writing proof an now i see your counter exemple wich seems prerfectly legit. g would 1 on infnite number of one which is stable by translation.

Comment: @Idéophage Btw what you say after is - instead of +, was my first theorem aptempt and surpsingly its false, i let you think :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120236/discussion-between-ideophage-and-heyheykhey).